# Can't dynamically connect to the `destruction` signal of dynamically created Item

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

`MyObj` is the following component:

```
Item {
    id:root
    signal foo()
    property string bar: "bar"
    Component.onCompleted: root.foo()
}
```

When creating it dynamically via [`Qt.createComponent(...)` -> `comp.createObject(...)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) it is possible to connect JS functions to all signals, except [`destruction`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#destruction-signal)

Following code:

```
var comp = Qt.createComponent('MyObj.qml');
var finish = () => {
    if(comp.status === Component.Error) {
        console.log("Error loading component:", comp.errorString())
        return
    }
    if(comp.status !== Component.Ready) {
        console.log("Component not ready")
        return
    }
    var obj = comp.createObject(mainWindow, {})
    if(obj === null) {
        console.log('Error creating object')
        return
    }
    obj.foo.connect(() => console.log('foo!'))
    obj.barChanged.connect(() => console.log('barChanged!'))
    obj.destruction.connect(() => console.log('destruction!'))
}
if(comp.status !== Component.Loading)
    finish();
else
    comp.statusChanged.connect(finish);
```

produces the error:

> qrc:/main.qml:32: TypeError: Cannot call method 'connect' of undefined

exactly at the line with `obj.destruction.connect(...)`

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) doesn't mention any such restriction.

What's wrong?

Putting:

```
Component.onDestruction: console.log("#destruction")
```

in `MyObj` works as usual, but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize JS needs the same syntax as QML for accessing properties of the superclass.

The following works just fine:

```
obj.Component.destruction.connect(() => console.log('destruction!'))
```

Comment: You are not accessing a property or signal of the super class, you are accessing the signal of an attached object provided by the `Component` attaching type. There is no different in syntax when accessing a property/signal/function of the super class, but I believe you can't be connected to the `QObject::destroyed` signal in QML since the object is actually destroyed and the engine can't handle that.